# String Index - sub string and main string Something is not working properly

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I want the sub-array array has been tested in main array.
but i get error.

The test I'm doing is right or need to add more conditions?

Finally, I need to print the index of the main array, in which sub-string begins.

Example to answer:

```
String m="cd e";
String n="abcd efghi";

print>>>> 2(the index in n String)
```

the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:         
 String  index out of range: 4
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at test1.main(test1.java:10)
```

The code:

```
    String m="cd e";
    String n="abcd efghi";


    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n.length(); j++) {
            if(m.charAt(j)==n.charAt(i) )
                if(m.charAt(j+1)==n.charAt(i+1))
                    System.out.println(i);          
        }   
     }
```

thank's.

Comment: you dont need this again if(m.charAt(j+1)==n.charAt(i+1))

Comment: change 'm.length()' to 'm.length() - 1' in the loops and what do you think j+1 will do if you are testing last item?

Comment: Few hints: (1) your `i` seems to be iterator for `m` and `j` for `n`, so why are you using `i` for `n`? (you should name your variables more reasonably, even `i1` `i2` `n1` `n2` would cause less confusion). (2) what value will `i+1` have when `i` will be equal to `m.length-1`? Is there any `charAt` at position pointed by that value?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
You look through with the n because it has the longest length. I hope this helps.
         String m="cd e";
        String n="abcd efghi";

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) {
            if (i <= m.length()){ // to prevent indexoutOfbound exception
                if(m.charAt(j)==n.charAt(i) ) {
                    System.out.println(m.charAt(j)+"-->"+i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
c-->2
d-->3
 -->4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package default1;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String m="cd e";
    String n="abcd efghi";

    System.out.println(n.indexOf(m));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int index = 0;
    boolean previousMatch = false;
    while (i < n.length()) {
        if (j == m.length()) {
            break;
        }
        if (m.charAt(j) == n.charAt(i)) {
            if (!previousMatch) {
                previousMatch = true;
                index = i;
            }
            j++;
        } else {
            previousMatch = false;
            index = 0;
            j = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (previousMatch)
        System.out.println(index);
```